# How to get access to cookies in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

My permissions look the following way:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://localhost:8000/*",
  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/*",
  "cookies",
  "bookmarks"]
```

And I can make queries to the API using **withCredentials**. That obviously means that host permissions are correct, otherwise, I would have received CORS error. The problem is that:

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({ url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' }, (result) => console.log(result));
```

returns an empty list. I have also tried: "*://127.0.0.1:8000/*", but with no success. MDN documentation(I am using Chrome, but it's documentation is really sparse says that:

http://www.example.com/

1. An add-on with this host permission may:
2. Read a non-secure cookie for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), with any path. Read a non-secure cookie for
   .example.com, with any path.
3. Write a secure or non-secure cookie for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with any path.
4. Write a secure or non-secure cookie for .example.com with any path.

So my permission file looks correct. I am querying cookies from the background.js file. Cookies are non-empty for the queried site.

Comment: The code is correct AFAICT and it works for me so the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it return the list of cookies for the website or an empty list?

Comment: Yes, like I said, it works for me.

Comment: That's pretty strange. I have created a test project with only those settings: https://github.com/fatalispm/cookie-test/commit/2be3a590fcf526e041db329f55d30b9b610cc3d1 . It's not working.

Comment: I didn't specify the port in `permissions` though, AFAIK it's not needed there.

Comment: You are right! You can make an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line:  **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**, you don't need to provide a port in settings. "http://127.0.0.1/" works just fine and I can read cookies. If you need access to all cookies you can just use **<all_urls>.**